# how to get value ckeditor when use mix('dist/js/ckeditor-classic.js') }}

Tags: javascript, php, html, ckeditor5

i am using ckeditor5 by adding this script  . I want to get the value but I get the error Uncaught ReferenceError: ClassicEditor is not defined. this is what i did and don't know where is wrong, can you help me?
[image code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LHcQl.png)
[image bug](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FYgNY.png)

```
<script src="{{ mix('dist/js/ckeditor-classic.js') }}"></script>
<script>
    const editorElement = document.querySelector('.editor');
    ClassicEditor
        .create(document.querySelector('.editor'))
        .then(editor => {
            console.log(editor);
        })
        .catch(error => {
            console.error(error);
        });

    function getDataFromDescriptionEditorEditor() {
        return ClassicEditor.getData();
    }
    $(".btn-primary").on('click', function() {
        console.log(getDataFromDescriptionEditorEditor());
    })
</script>
```

Comment: Make sure it's actually loaded the correct file, or try their CDN and see if there's any difference.